# How to create textNode for radio button with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a radio button with JavaScript. It's easy with HTML i.e `<input type="radio" name="sType" value="m">MALE`, so far with JS I'm able to create `<input type="radio" name="sType" value="m">` but I don't know how to create `MALE` text Node for it. Also I want to append this form in 3rd div element of body with `id='user_input'` so what should be it's DOM navigation? 
Here is my code:

```
document.getElementsById('user_input').childNodes[0].appendChild(f);
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute("id", "myForm");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"ride_test.php");

var radio1 = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
radio1.setAttribute("id","radio1");
radio1.setAttribute('type',"radio");
radio1.setAttribute('name',"sType");
radio1.setAttribute('value',"m");
f.appendChild(radio1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a description to the radio button, you should create a `label` and insert the description of the radio there.

```
let f = document.createElement("form");

let radio1 = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
radio1.setAttribute("id","radio1");
radio1.setAttribute('type',"radio");
radio1.setAttribute('name',"sType");
radio1.setAttribute('value',"m");

let label = document.createElement('label');
label.textContent = "MALE";
f.appendChild(radio1);
f.appendChild(label);
document.body.appendChild(f)
```

You can also create a text node and append after input, but this is not recommended option:

```
//The same as above
let desc = document.createTextNode("MALE")

f.appendChild(radio1)
f.appendChild(desc);
document.body.appendChild(f)`
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dpu54as9/

Comment: How to show this form after the click on button inside the 3rd <div> tag of body?@Mat.Now

Answer (score 0):

Input tags are auto-enclosing tags and should not have any text. You need to use a label tag alongside (you can check [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)), such as:

```
<input type="radio" name="sType" id="radio1" value="m"/>
<label for="radio1">MALE</label>
```

And to do so in your code, simply create a new label element, set its text and append to the form:

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute("id", "myForm");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"ride_test.php");


var radio1 = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
var label1 = document.createElement("label");
// link label to input through id
label1.setAttribute("for", "radio1");
label1.innerHTML = "MALE";

radio1.setAttribute("id","radio1");
radio1.setAttribute('type',"radio");
radio1.setAttribute('name',"sType");
radio1.setAttribute('value',"m");
f.appendChild(radio1);
f.appendChild(label1);
```

Note that the IDs are unique, meaning you can't have more than 1 id with the same name simultaneously on the DOM. The best way to achieve what you want is to change `user_input` to a class (which is not unique), and then append to DOM as follows:

```
document.body.getElementsByClassName('user_input')[2].appendChild(f);
```